# Реализация функций изменения файлов

Tags: php, io, linux

Всем здравствуйте.

Необходимо реализовать следующие функции. Web-интерфейс, соответственно, на php (желательно 5). Все настроил. Теперь нужны скрипты для управления файлами, т.е. необходимо в Web`е внести в поля корректировки, нажав на кнопку изменяет, добавляет, допустим, правила для iptables или другое. В принципе нужны лишь сами функции. 
Всем заранее спасибо за помощь.

Вот в принципе, что нужно сделать. Открыть нужный файл и вывести его на странице в виде строк (чтобы строки переносились, отражались в виде столбца и каждая в начале нумеровалась) не обязательно,но желательно.

Хотя бы данные преподнести. Дальше можно уже по идее что-то придумать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите добавлять правила для iptables, то используйте

```
shell_exec("iptables -A ...");
```

ну или удалять

```
shell_exec("iptables -D ...");
```

Читать конфиг iptables и писать туда что-то нет необходимости :)

А если же все таки именно читать, то:

```
$arData = file("/etc/filename");
```

где $arData - это массив строк файла вида 0 => 'Первая строка', 1 => 'Вторая' ...
Если файл с конфигом очень большой, то:

```
$f = fopen("/etc/filename", "r");
while (!feof($f)) {
$line = fgets($f);
...
}
fclose($f);
```

Писать в файл также:

```
$f = fopen("/etc/filename", "w");
fwrite($f, "any data");
fclose($f);
```

Comment: отличное описание,теперь тогда уже можно ставить вопрос иначе,как все это дело завернуть на отображение в web посредством форм и иных приблуд.)))

Comment: Ответ ниже

Answer (score 1):

```
fopen()
fread()
fwrite()
fclose()
```

Скрипты писать уже самому придется, потому как структура содержимого у файлов разная (iptables **или** другое).
К тому же не думаю, что получится из php писать системные файлы.

Comment: т.е. я используя fopen() открываю файл,fread() его читаю(кстати тут возникает вопрос - как читать построчно,ведь в правилах iptables используются по строке на правило). далее записываю fwrite() и закрываю тем самым файл,который я редактировал через fclose().
как тогда правильно выводить функции fread() и fwrite() на форму?????

Comment: а чтобы писать системные файлы,я просто запускать систему сразу из под рута буду))

Comment: Всё, что вы говорите, - просто ужас. Это полнейшее безумие - позволять веб-серверу и PHP выполняться от рута. "Далее записываю fwrite() и закрываю тем самым файл, который я редактировал через fclose()" - создаётся впечатление, что вы не разобрались, что эти функции вообще делают и зачем нужны. "Как тогда правильно выводить функции fread() и fwrite()" - функции нельзя выводить на форму, их можно только вызвать. В общем, я бы на вашем месте не стал бы даже пытаться править серьёзные системные файлы - это слишком опасно, когда вы правите их, не разобравшись в вопросе.

Comment: дело в том,что с Линухом я знаком не первый день,суть не в том,чтобы не править,а разобраться,как правильно использовать функции для корректировки файлов,на данном этапе можно вообще любые файлы корректировать,вносить изменения.
помогите разобраться,как реализовать редактирование файла через форму??? помогите)))

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['cmd']) {
        shell_exec($_POST['cmd']);
    }
?>
<form action="me.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="cmd"><input type="submit" value="Post!">
</form>
```

Comment: я так понимаю в me.php надо вписать те самые функции

$f = fopen("/etc/filename", "r");
while (!feof($f)) {
$line = fgets($f);
...
}
fclose($f);



или 



$f = fopen("/etc/filename", "w");
fwrite($f, "any data");
fclose($f);


точнее чтобы прочесть 1е. а записать второе, и лучше наверно тогда сделать два разных файла))
верно?

Answer (score 0):

Ну так прочтите про эти функции [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php), [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) и [fclose](http://). Прочтите [туториал](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/8/1/3) по работе с файлами в конце концов.

Comment: спасибо,буду смотреть.